# How can i define in xsd that a simple/complex type contain another XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

Is possibile in xsd that medicalDetails may contain another XML, not another complex type but any other xml that isn't define yet.

```
<xs:complexType name="personinfo">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="medicalDetails" type="xs:medicalDetails"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="fullpersoninfo">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="personinfo">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="medicalDetails">

<!--This type contain another XML  -->

</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `xs:any` to permit arbitrary content, like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="medicalDetails">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

[Here's a link to more documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp).

This means that anything can go under `medicalDetails`.